# Error when doing a project transfer from oracle repo to eapx file

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am running a Sparx EA Project transfer from a oracle Repo to a EAPX file for a backup.. While it runs I get the error below.
Is this something I should be concerned about ? Is there anyway to fix the underlying cause of the error ?

[image: Project Transfer Error]

Thanks

Rob

Comment: First thing to try is to run a project integrity check, and fix the errors. On the other hand t_stereotypes is not really that important, so you can certainly ignore that error.

Comment: Or you can erase the content of that table prior to tranfering it. Always keep backups!